# Selenium IDE saving test in wrong order

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

I have 2 simple tests in Selenium IDE, when executed from IDE the order is being maintained. But when I use the Side file to run using Selenium Side runner then order is different.

As you can see the test order here is 1- Amazon Login and then 2- Search Product. This does work fine when executed from IDE but when I use the Selenium Side runner with Selenium grid then Search product is being executed first and then Login. Not sure what's the problem here.

[image: Selenium Test]

Note: When I open the .side file in text editor then also the order is reversed this is the reason behind the execution. i.e. when saving the project in IDE it's doing something wrong.
I don't have the Run in parallel enabled.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: DId you change the order in the IDE & then save the suite file (not just the test files)?

Comment: Yes,  Did that.  But no luck